# Angular form auto-resubmit (event triggered to early)

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I want to make a form that is submitted automatically on each change. I tried to make a root model and watch it for changed. The issue is that my directives pre-populate the models in the link function and the watch is triggered too early.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/oH2Homlr7efu0IctoyQF?p=preview

So I have two questions:

1. How to know when a "real" change has happened?
2. How to submit the form? (is it just $('form').submit()?)

**UPDATE**

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7OOSuaf7i3ay70X6WGun?p=preview

I updated the code to display the query string and watch for `form.$dirty`, but the value isn't submited. I think `ng-model` doesn't update `input[value]`. Any ideas on how to solve this?

PS. I don't want to use ajax request to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can watch form.dirty flag instead of form which will give you the correct trigger. I'm using like this.

```
   $scope.$watch('form.$dirty',function(newValue, oldValue){
             if(newValue){//if isDrty=true
               console.log('resubmit', newValue);
           }
     },true);
```

For the second question , you can do an ajax request using [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) service to the server with the form (json object)

```
$http.post('/someUrl', $scope.form).success(successCallback);
```

Comment: I want to submit the form in the classic way, not using Ajax. If I do $('form').submit() the values are not sent.